# Sharepoint and OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I have an issue within a corporate network that nobody internally seems to know the answer to so I thought I would ask here.

Having recently been upgraded to Office 365 we use Sharepoint.  When uploading documents to the Sharepoint site it appears to save them in a newly created OneDrive folder.

Anyone with access to the SharePoint site will find a link to the document store within their personal OneDrive.

So my question is whether anyone knows if this is the default behaviour and if the files are actually being stored in OneDrive.

The reason I ask is that some documents for governance reasons cannot be stored on SharePoint or OneDrive but there does not appear to be any way of changing where files are stored.

Thanks for any insight.

The reason I ask is there does not appear to be any way with the updated office suite to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, the problem seems to be related to the syncing of files from SharePoint to OneDrive, you can try to stop the sync and see if the problem can be solved.
For detailed steps, please refer to:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-syncing-a-library-with-the-onedrive-for-work-or-school-app-a7e41f1f-3a98-4ca7-9443-f10250688330